# How to compare date and time field with '>' OR '<' in rails.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have event table in that All the events are stored with column "event_start_date" with date and time datatype.

now from that Event table I want to get only Upcoming Events for that I used

```
Event.where("event_start_date > ?" Time.now)
```

but I got a syntax error.

What is the problem can you help me.?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event.where("event_start_date > ?", Time.now)
```

You're missing a comma.